# Why does the <img> scale correctly and not the <div> when the window changes dimension?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a square on top of an img. When I reduce the window, the img is scaled proportionally, but the square does not change size at all?

Here is the html :

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11 col-md-11" style="position: relative;">         
      <img src="images/mur02-1200.jpg" class="superpose" id="img1" alt="mur01" style="visibility:visible;">              
      <img src="images/mur03-1200.jpg" class="superpose" id="img2" alt="mur02" style="visibility:hidden;">
      <div id="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css :

```
.superpose {
  position: absolute;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;

}

#square {
  position: absolute;
   width: 200px;  
   height:200px;
   background-color: orange;
   opacity: 0.5;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You've set an explicit width and height for the square in pixels. You can set it using `%` instead.

Comment: Use top padding trick on square to maintain proportions.

Comment: To make the `#square` responsive you can set `width: 100%; max-width: 200px;`.

Comment: @SalmanA congratulations ! Your trick workds, even if it's beyond logic for me :-) I will answer to the general thread with it

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed pixel width and height on that square - it can't change size that way (use percentages)

ADDED jsFiddle after comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c3wtcp5q/3/

Note: The container for the image and the `#square` DIV now has `height: 66.66vw;`, which corresponds to the height/width proportion of the image (2/3). Since the image is 100% wide (which equals 100vw here), that's the way to get a correct height setting for its container, which is necessary when using percentage values for height, as I wrote in my comment. Similarly, I got the percentage values for the suare DIV's width and height.

Also, it's necessary to use a z-index when having two absolutely positioned elements in one parent.

Comment: Well, both width and height calculate percentage from the corresponding *value*  of the parent, which is especially tricky concerning `height`: Also the parent element needs to have a height definition for this to work. And if *this* height is also a percentage value, again the great-parent needs a height definition, and so on, up to the `body`and `html`elements, which is why you often see the rule `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: jsfiddle.net/moiamy/yjo6j7k3/1/#

Comment: note the addition to my answer and the jsfiddle in it. The main point is to have a defined height setting for the container (and the z-index).

Comment: Yes sorry I missed your point Johannes. Nevertheless, when I now add html, body { height: 100%; } I can't see any square if I set the square width in %.

Comment: with the `vw` unit in the height setting the height is independent from html and body height

Comment: My fiddle *has* `html, body { height: 100%; }` in it! Must be another reason in your case...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you set a fixed width. Try this:

```
#square {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: orange;
   opacity: 0.5;
   max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hybrid. But with this scenario, the square disappear.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle showing that the box dissappears? I'm doing it on my computer and the box shows just fine

Comment: I see. Since you are using absolute positioning, the height is 0 by default... try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap class img-responsive in img tag to make responsive images.
For demo: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. Here is the solution. Thanks to all of you who help me to advance in this non-rationnal HTML world (especially to @SalmanA and @Johannes)

As i wanted a multilayer approach, I use the embedded *absolute* **div** & **img** in a *relative* **div**.

Then as we want the square to adjust itself its size when we resize the window, we must use padding-top to put the initial size :

```
#square1 {
   position: absolute;
   padding-top:150px;
   width: 50%;
}
```

I have no idea why this is working, but it works :-)